# How to write flex and bison file parsing this language?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

Let's define a language:

```
VAR := [0-9A-Za-z_]+
Exp := VAR 
   | VAR,'=',VAR 
   | '(', Exp, ')'
   | Exp, '&', Exp 
   | Exp ,'|', Exp
```

eg: "( a = b ) & ( c | (d=e) ) "is legal

I've read the YASS & Lex manual, but I'm totally confused , I just want the compiler that can parse this language 
Can you tell  me how to write the flex&bison configure file for this language?

I've  done so far:

file a.l:

```
%{

#include <string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "y.tab.h"

%}

%%

("&"|"and"|"AND")   { return AND; }
("|"|"or"|"OR")   { return OR; }
("="|"eq"|"EQ")   { return EQ; }
([A-Za-z0-9_]+)   { return VAR;}
("(")   { return LB ;}
(")")   { return RB ;}
("\n")   { return LN ;}



%%

int main(void)
{
 yyparse();
 return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
 return 0;
}

int yyerror(void)
{
  printf("Error\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

file a.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%token AND OR EQ VAR LB RB LN

%left AND OR
%left EQ

%%

line : 
       | exp LN{ printf("LN: %s",$1);}
;

exp:    VAR             { printf("var:%s",$1);}
    |  VAR EQ VAR      { printf("var=:%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);}
    |  exp AND exp      { printf("and :%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);}
    |  exp OR exp      { printf("or :%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);}
    |  LB exp RB      { printf("abstract :%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);}    

    ;
```

Now I edited file as Chris Dodd guided,it seems much better(at least the lex worked fine),but I get output like this:

```
disk_path>myprogram
a=b
var=:(null) (null) (null)LN: (null)ab=b
Error
```

So, why the function printf output null? and after input the second ,it prompt Error and exit the program?

Comment: Show us what you tried.  I'll give a few hints in a response, but you really should show what you tried first

Answer (score 1):

First write a lex file to tokenize input (and print out what it sees)

You want to introduce the terminals:

- `[0-9A-Za-z_]+ --> VAR`
- `( --> LPAREN` and `) --> RPAREN`
- `& --> AND`
- `| --> OR`
- `= --> EQUAL`

and just print out a word for each.  For your example

```
( a = b ) & ( c | (d=e) ) --> LPAREN VAR EQUAL VAR RPAREN AND LPAREN VAR OR LPAREN VAR EQUAL VAR RPAREN RPAREN
```

This is doable in pure lex.  When you do this, update your response and we can talk about the next step

Answer (score 1):

Your lex rule `("[0-9A-Za-z_]+")` will match (only) the literal string `[0-9A-Za-z_]+` -- get rid of the `"` characters to have it be a pattern to match any identifier or number.

Your yacc code does not match your lex code for punctuation -- the lex code returns `AND` for `&` while the yacc code is expecting an `&` -- so either change the lex code to return `'&'` or change the yacc code to use the token `AND`, and similarly for `|`, `(`, and `)`.  You might also want to ignore spaces in the lex code (rather than treating them as errors).  You also have no lex rule to match and return `'\n'`, even though you use that in your yacc grammar.

Your yacc code is otherwise correct, but is ambiguous, thus giving you shift/reduce conflicts.  That's because your grammar is ambiguous -- an input like `a&b|c` can be parsed as either `(a&b)|c` or `a&(b|c)`.  You need to decide how that ambiguity should be resolved and reflect that in your grammar -- either by using more non-terminals, or by using yacc's built-in precedence support for resolving this kind of ambiguity.  If you stick the declarations:

```
%left '|'
%left '&'
```

in the top of your yacc file, that will resolve the ambiguity by making both `&` and `|` left associative, and `&` higher precedence than `|`, which would be the normal interpretation.

**Edit**

The problem you have now is that you never define YYSTYPE (either directly or with %union) in your .y file and you never set yylval in your .l file.  The first problem means that `$1` etc are just `int`s, not pointers (so it makes no sense to try to print them with `%s` -- you should be getting a warning from your C compiler over that).  The second problem means that they never have a value anyways, so its just always the default 0 value of an uninitialized global variable

The easiest fix would be to add

```
%union {
    const char *name;
}
%token <name> VAR LB RB LN
%left <name> AND OR
%left <name> EQ
%type <name> expr
```

to the top of the yacc file.  Then change the all the lex rules to be something like

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+)   { yylval.name = strdup(yytext); return VAR;}
```

Finally, you also need to change the bison actions for expr to set `$$`, eg:

```
|  LB exp RB      { asprintf(&$$, "%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);  printf("abstract: %s\n", $$); }
```

This will at least work, though it will leak lots of memory for the allocated strings.

The last problem you have is that your `line` rule only matches a single line, so a second line of input causes an error.  You need a recursive rule like:

```
line: /* empty */
    | line exp LN { printf....
```

Comment: Thank you,I edited .l and .y file as you said,But the new problem comes,see the description above